# Scrollview not scrolling subview in autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

I have a view controller with a scrollview.

The scrollview has a sub View (content view) which is a view I have copied from another VC. I cannot get the scroll to work, I have tried:

- Set constraints of scrollview against the container (pinned top/bottom/sides =0)
- Setting Horziontal and vertical spacing of Content view against the scrollview which also didn't work
- Set the content view to superview Leading/Trailing space to container margin, Top space to top layout guide and Bottom Space to bottom layout guide - still no scroll
- Have also tried to set the scrollview size in viewdidload :

  scrollView.scrollEnabled = true;
          scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size;

And no scroll.

I am possibly missing something basic here but although have tried numerous tutorials on line I can't get my head around using scrollview.

[image: View Hiearchy and VC]

Pop up when dragging content view to scroll view
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content view is not embedded in your scroll view.

Comment: Ok so how to Embed? Tried dragging the content view in view hierarchy window to the scrollview but only options for vertical/horizontal spacing appeared in pop up

Comment: You should be able to drag the content view into the scroll view in the sidebar. Don't use any keyboard modifier keys.

Comment: Do NOT press any keyboard buttons. It looks like you use the ctrl button.

Comment: Just using a mouse pad on a laptop, right clicking and dragging

Comment: Well, left click and drag then :).

Comment: Eventually moved it as a direct subview of scrollview so thanks. However got allot of Misplaced view errors and Scrollview as ambiguous height, tried updating Frames then view disappeared /....might be better starting from scratch

Comment: Yeah that is a very annoying side effect. You will need to create new constraints for all the sub views. Starting from scratch is sometimes easier indeed...

Answer (score 1):

to Scroll `UIScrollView` you need following Steps

1. pin `UIScrollView` with its `SuperView` from all four side Top, Left, Bottom, Right
2. Add a `contentView` (UIView) in ScrollView and pin it with `UIScrollView` with 0 margin from all four sides. also add equal width constraint.
3. add subviews to `contentView` make sure all view pinned with constraint from top bottom & also add Height Constraint for subviews.

no need to set any property or content size in code.